# php join multiple json files and group them by id

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, foreach

I have multiple json files, i need to join them all to gather to create my dynamic menu.

this is the current output

```
{
    "Dashboard": {
        "parent": "Dashboard",
        "url": "#\/dashboard",
        "submenu": []
    },
    "HRM": {
        "submenu": [
            {
                "title": "Holiday",
                "url": "#\/holidays"
            },
            {
                "divider": "true"
            },
            {
                "header": "Header 2"
            },
            {
                "title": "Again...a link.",
                "url": "errrr"
            }
        ]
    } }
```

this is the desired output

```
{
    "parent": "Dashboard",
    "url": "#\/dashboard",
    "submenu": []
}, {
    "parent": "HRM",
    "submenu": [{
            "title": "Holiday",
            "url": "#\/holidays"
    }, {
            "divider": "true"
    }, {
            "header": "Header 2"
    }, {
            "title": "Again...a link.",
            "url": "errrr"
    }, {
            "header": "Holiday"
    },
        {
            "title": "list",
            "url": ""
                },
        {
            "title": "test",
            "url": ""
                }]
}
```

here is my PHP code

```
$files = \File::allFiles($directory);
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            if (preg_match("/config.json/i", $file) && \File::size($file) >0) {
                $menu =json_decode(\File::get($file), TRUE)['menu'];
               // $menu = $menu['menu'];

                $id = $menu['parent'];
                    if(!empty($menu['submenu'])){
                        $result[$id]['submenu'] = $menu['submenu'];
                    }else{
                        $result[$id] = $menu;
                    }
            }
        }
```

JSON files 1 example

```
{
    "menu": {
        "parent": "Dashboard",
        "url": "#/dashboard",

        "submenu": [
            ]
    }

}
```

JSON file 2 example

```
   {
        "menu": {
            "parent": "HRM",
            "submenu": [
                {
                    "title": "Holiday",
                    "url": "#/holidays"
                    },
                {
                    "divider": "true"
                    },
                {
                    "header": "Header 2"
                    },
                {
                    "title": "Again...a link.",
                    "url": "errrr"
                    }
                ]
        }

    }
```

JSON file 3 example

```
   {
        "menu": {
            "parent": "HRM",
            "submenu": [
                {
                    "header": "Holiday"
                    },
                {
                    "title": "list",
                    "url": ""
                    },
                {
                    "title": "test",
                    "url": ""
                    }
                ]
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code,

```
$files = \File::allFiles($directory);
$result = array();

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    if (preg_match("/config.json/i", $file) && \File::size($file) >0) {
    $parent = $menu['parent'];
    //checker is used to see if document is already added under an existing parent id
    $checker = true;

    foreach($result as $key=>$value){
        if(is_array($value) && $value["parent"]==$parent){
            $checker = false;
            //merging the submenus of equal parent ids
            $submenuSet = array();
            if(!empty($value["submenu"]) && is_array($value["submenu"])){
                foreach($value["submenu"] as $value1){
                    $submenuSet[] = $value1;
                }
            }
            if(!empty($menu["submenu"]) && is_array($menu["submenu"])){
                foreach($menu["submenu"] as $value2){
                    $submenuSet[] = $value2;
                }
            }
            $value["submenu"] = $submenuSet;
        }
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }

    //if a new parent id add it to results
    if($checker){
        $result[] = $menu;
    }
}
}
```

the output would be like this,

```
[
  {
    "parent": "Dashboard",
    "url": "#\/dashboard",
    "submenu": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "parent": "HRM",
    "submenu": [
      {
        "title": "Holiday",
        "url": "#\/holidays"
      },
      {
        "divider": "true"
      },
      {
        "header": "Header 2"
      },
      {
        "title": "Again...a link.",
        "url": "errrr"
      },
      {
        "header": "Holiday"
      },
      {
        "title": "list",
        "url": ""
      },
      {
        "title": "test",
        "url": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```